# xmltodict(xml) returns dictionary values with backslashes

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I want `xmltodict.parse(XML)`to return `"XELTA\LMOR\CCS\CIP\CIP_3_2"`. Instead `xmltodict` to converts XML content to dictionary returns strings with double backslashes. `XML_Input ="XELTA\LMOR\CCS\CIP\CIP_3_2"`
returns = `xmltodict.parse(XML_Input)`
Returns = `{"XELTA\LMOR\CCS\CIP\CIP_3_2"}`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Returning with double slash "XELTA|\LMOR\\CCS\\CIP\\CIP_3_2"

Comment: Those double backslashes are just the Python representation of a single backslashes. Try printing the string to see its actual contents.

Comment: Yes printing looks fine, when i add this to MongoDB I see that same behavior

Comment: My point was that the extras really aren't in the string so it should work fine.